# maximum Fourier coefficient among all bounded real continuous periodic functions

Tags: continuity, fourier-series, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\mathcal C$ be the space of real continuous $2\pi$-periodic functions bounded in absolute value by 1.

Can we compute
$$c_s := \sup_{f\in\mathcal C} \left|\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-isx}f(x)dx\right|$$
for any $s\in\mathbb Z$? In other words, what is the biggest $s$-Fourier coefficient in the space?

Obviously all $c_s$ are upper bounded by $2\pi$ and $c_0 =2\pi$. Moreover we can restrict $\mathcal C$ to the functions whose maximum is exactly 1 (that probably is not compact, pity).

Moreover, by choosing the  probably most obvious candidate $f(x) = \cos(sx)$, one finds that $c_s\ge \pi$ for every $s$.

Notice that for complex-valued $f(x)$ we get $c_s=2\pi$ for any $s$, but can we prove that for real functions the best is half of that?

Comment: @Conrad Wait, by Parseval $a_n^2 + b_n^2\le \|f\|^2 /\pi \le 2$, not 1...

Comment: yes you are correct and I was hasty; from Parseval one gets only that $|c_n| \le \sqrt 2 \pi$; however, this uses only the hypothesis $||f||_2 \le 1$ not the full hypothesis $||f||_{\infty} \le 1$ and the equality case for the two norms when the $n$ coefficient is nonzero is not real anymore for $n \ge 1$

Comment: the conjecture is incorrect and one can get $c_n \ge 4-\epsilon$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's give an elementary proof that $c_n \le 4$ and one can get $c_n=4-\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0$, so for fixed $N \ge 1$ find $f$ continuous, periodic, real and bounded by $1$ for which $c_N=4-\epsilon$, while it will be clear that $4$ cannot be attained with continuous functions.

Let's fix $N \ge 1$ and assume $c_N \ne 0$ and let $t_0$ its argument so $e^{-it_0}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-iNx}f(x)dx =e^{-it_0}c_N=|c_N|>0$

But this means that $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-iN(x+t_0/N)}f(x)dx >0$ or with $g(x)=f(x+t_0/N)$ we have $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-iNx}g(x)dx >0$ using the change of variable $x \to x+t_0/N$ and the periodicity of $f$.

(Added per comments) But the integral above being real (and positive) means that its real part is positive and equal to it and its imaginary part is zero. Using that $g$ is real (here is crucial) we get that:

$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-iNx}g(x)dx =\int_0^{2\pi}  g(x)  \cos Nx dx >0$ (real part) and $\int_0^{2\pi}  g(x)  \sin Nx dx =0$ (imaginary part)

But $|g(x)| \le 1$ means that $|g(x)  \cos Nx| \le |\cos Nx|$ so $|\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-iNx}g(x)dx| \le \int_0^{2\pi}|\cos Nx|dx=4$ hence $|c_N| \le 4$ and we clearly get equality for $f(x)=\text{sign} \cos Nx$.

Now $f$ is not continuous but clearly can be approximated as well as we want by continuous functions for which $c_N$ will be as close to $4$ as we wish.

Comment: $g$ is real doesn't imply that integrated by the sine it is zero... Take for example $g(x) = \sin(Nx)$...

Comment: You only have proved that $|c_N|\ge 4$ with this

Comment: In general you are right but here we proved that the integral of $g$ against $e^{iNx}$ is real (and positive) by our choice of $t_0$ hence of $g$ so the imaginary part of the integral is zero and that is the integral of $g$ against the sine; will edit to make it clear